# Changing AOSP Overlays with a System Property

Tags: android-source, android-theme

I'm working in a custom AOSP build for which I made an overlay that changes the device default theme. I've put those overlays in:

```
device/overlay/framework/base/core/res/res
```

Now I'd like to make a different overlay for the same build in such a way that changing a property will change the overlay that is applied.

So for example I set

```
setprop persist.brand brand1
```

And i see overlay1, then:

```
setprop persist.brand brand2
```

and see overlay2.

I've been digging into RRO and was able to change some overlays with custom apks but I have no clue how to tie that to a system property.

EDIT:

I found that I can achieve similar results by compiling rro apks using

```
include $(BUILD_RRO_PACKAGE)
```

in the Android.mk.

What I noticed is that in the build_rro_package.mk there is a comment that says

```
## Set LOCAL_RRO_THEME to the theme name if the package should apply only to
## a particular theme as set by ro.boot.vendor.overlay.theme system property.
```

What I understand is that I can group many rro packages into the same LOCAL_RRO_THEME name and then activate or deactivate them together using the ro.boot.vendor.overlay.theme property. If this is correct then it's exactly what I was looking for

The problem I face now is that when I set LOCAL_RRO_THEME with a different name than the LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME the overlay won't show when I list them with:

```
cmd overlay list
```

This doesn't make much sense, but maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

which AOSP version are you working on? There's a runtime overlay feature in AOSP 9(though Google has not publish the document yet, but it's there). On the earlier version, this can't be done because overlay system is done on compile time. If you really want to change resources on the runtime, you need to modify the framework, especially `PackageManagerService`

Comment: I'm working on AOSP 8.0.0. Sad to know this isn't possible. Right now I'm doing it in compile time defining different PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS directories for each compilation but it isn't the best.

Comment: @Nico.A I’m not sure if AOSP 8.0 has this feature. Have a try, I got strong feeling that AOSP 8 has already support the runtime overlay.

Comment: Good thing, I found AOSP 8 has support, bad thing I don't know how to use it. I'll update my original question with what I've found so far.